# Скрыть/удалить из блока существующий элемент при появлении/добавлении нового

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Имеем такие блоки. В **подменю 2 Блок2** появляется новая строка, при ее появлении нужно убрать другую строку.

Когда появляется эта: `<a class="hdhdhd" href=" " >HD каналы</a>`
нужно скрыть эту: `<a class=" tototo" href=" " >Торрент тв</a>`,
причем в Блок1  `<a class=" tototo" href=" " >Торрент тв</a>` должна остаться.

Можно ли это проделать стилями, чем-нибудь вроде:

```
/* это не работает конечно  */

.men777 .hdhdhd + .tototo {
    display: none;
}
```

Или скриптами, например при наличии в **class="men777"** слова **HD каналы**,
скрыть **class=" tototo"**.

Имеется JavaScript:

```
$('.hdhdhd:contains("HD каналы")').parent().addClass("tototo")();
```

И соответствующий ему CSS стиль:

```
.tototo {
  display: none;
}
```

Но это не совсем то. Вот разметка:

```html
<li>
  <div class="bbb"><a class=" " href=" ">БЛОК 1</a>

    <div class="oooa">
      <a class=" " href=" ">-------- поддменю 1 БЛОК 1</a>
      <div class="men444">
        <a class=" " href=" ">Все каналы</a> <br>
        <a class=" " href=" ">Развлекательные</a> <br>
        <a class=" " href=" ">Популярные</a> <br>
        <a class=" " href=" ">Новостные</a> <br>

      </div>
      <!--menuuuuuu-->

      <a class=" " href=" ">-------- поддменю 2 БЛОК 1</a>
      <div class="men777">
        <a class=" " href=" ">Спутниковые</a> <br>
        <a class=" tototo" href=" ">Торрент тв</a> <br>

      </div>
      <!--menuuuuuu-->


      <div class=" 555"></div>
      <div class="rakana"></div>

    </div>
    <!--oooa-->
    <div class="rakana222"></div>
  </div>
  <!--div bbb-->
  <div class="content_left">
  </div>
  <!--content_left-->
</li>
<!--li-->
<li>
  <div class="bbb"><a class=" " href=" ">БЛОК 2</a>

    <div class="oooa">
      <a class=" " href=" ">-------- поддменю 1 БЛОК 2</a>
      <div class="men444">
        <a class=" " href=" ">Все каналы</a> <br>
        <a class=" " href=" ">Развлекательные</a> <br>
        <a class=" " href=" ">Популярные</a> <br>
        <a class=" " href=" ">Новостные</a> <br>

      </div>
      <!--menuuuuuu-->

      <a class=" " href=" ">-------- поддменю 2 БЛОК 2</a>
      <div class="men777">
        <a class=" " href=" ">Спутниковые</a> <br>
        <a class="hdhdhd" href=" ">HD каналы</a> <br>
        <a class=" tototo" href=" ">Торрент тв</a> <br>

      </div>
      <!--menuuuuuu-->


      <div class=" 555"></div>
      <div class="rakana"></div>

    </div>
    <!--oooa-->
    <div class="rakana222"></div>
  </div>
  <!--div bbb-->
  <div class="content_left">
  </div>
  <!--content_left-->
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код, который вы указали в описании, правильный.

```
.men777 .hdhdhd + .tototo {
   display: none;
 }
```

Но для того, чтобы он начал работать, вам нужно убрать `<br>` между элементами.
Это связано с тем, что знак "+" выбирает элементы веб-страницы, у которых есть общий родитель и они находятся рядом друг с другом (т.е. являются соседними). А так как элементы с классами .hdhdhd и .tototo разделены тегом `<br>`, то они не являются соседними.